# I want my code to transfer the sheet tab to an excel file that I only know the partial name of

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub movedata_tab_to_2excelFile()



Windows("1excelfileInstructions and macrostest.xlsm"). _

Activate

Sheets("Data").Select

Sheets("Data").Copy Before:=Workbooks( _

"2excel File4253.xlsx").Sheets(3)

Windows("Instructions_and_macros_Test1.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

I want to move the data tab in [1excelfileInstructions and macrostest.xlsm] to 2excel File4253.xlsx and I have the macro stored in Instructions_and_macros_Test1.xlsm.

My problem is the excel file name of 2excel File4253.xlsx keeps changing and I only know the partial name of it. Is there anyway to run my code in which it can ignore the numbers before and after the excel file name like  adding asterisks/wild card to it example **excel File**

Comment: Did you try with `*` ?

Comment: @mikku yes I did it didnt work

Comment: Do you know the Path of Second File? Which Folder it is in ?

Comment: Try the Answer below

Comment: Is your code opening the workbook or it's already open when you run it? Could the macro prompt the user for the file and be responsible for opening it?

Comment: @Mathieu gunson it's already open when I run it. All the excel files in my code are all opened when I run it. And that is one way to do it but I would just like my code to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

if your Excel files are open then you can try to do the following:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim wbkCount As Long

    For wbkCount = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(wbkCount).Name Like "*excel File*" Then
            Debug.Print "This is the one!" & Workbooks(wbkCount).Name
            'do something
        End If
    Next wbkCount
End Sub
```

Basically the idea is for VBA to loop through all your open Workbooks and find the one that matches the name *excel File*. Once it is found, the code will perform the relevant action (replace `Debug.Print` and `'do something` lines with your `Copy` statement).

**Edit** - full code:

```
Sub movedata_tab_to_2excelFile()
    Dim wbkCount As Long

    Windows("1excelfileInstructions and macrostest.xlsm"). _
        Activate

    For wbkCount = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(wbkCount).Name Like "*excel File*" Then
            Sheets("Data").Copy Before:=Workbooks( _
                Workbooks(wbkCount).Name).Sheets(3)
        End If
    Next wbkCount

    Windows("Instructions_and_macros_Test1.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: That should work. I would only add `Exit For` inside the conditional, so as to bail out of the loop after the target book is identified.

Comment: @Justyna MK I'm a beginner at vba and im a little confused. Could you rewrite my code so I can understand it better.

Comment: @AmyWhite check my answer (I added the full code). Let me know if anything is unclear; basically we're looping through all opened Workbooks and see if any of them contains "excel File" in the name string. If yes, then copy "Data" sheet into this workbook. Consider also adding `Exit For` or `End Sub` (as per Mathieu's suggestion) in order to quit the macro once the action is completed (there's no need to continue looping through other opened Workbooks once "*excel File*" is found).

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU SOSOSOSO MUCH!

Comment: No problem at all. Please feel free to up-vote/mark my answer as correct. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this: (Tested)**

```
Sub movedata_tab_to_2excelFile()

fnd = Dir("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\" & "*excel File*.xlsm") 'Change the Folder Path

If fnd <> "" Then

    Workbooks("1excelfileInstructions and macrostest.xlsm.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Copy Before:=Workbooks(fnd).Sheets(3)

End If


End Sub
```

Also there is no Need for Activate and Select. You should always avoid those when working with VBA

Comment: I just tried it and the asteriks are not working. Is there another way to do this. I have all these excel files opened on my computer if that makes a difference.

Comment: I had a run time error of 9.

Comment: I would try to trace the file path using dir but I run into another problem of everything in that folder has a bunch of excel files with the same partial name of [(asterisk)***excel file**(asterik)] just different numbers before and after it. I just want my macro to apply it to the excel file that I currently have opened or to the most recent file in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub movedata_tab_to_2excelFile()

Dim s as string
Const path2SecondFile = "C:\"  'your path here, ending with \
s=dir(path2secondfile & "*File4253*.xlsx")  'or whatever wildcard pattern will find it
if s = "" then
   msgbox "Can't Find File",vbokonly,"File Not Found"
else
    dim found as boolean
    dim wb as workbook
    for each wb in workbooks
        if wb.name = s then
           'file already loaded
            found=true
            exit for
        end if
    next wb
    if not found then
         Workbooks.open(path2secondfile & s)  'if necessary
    end if
    with thisworkbook.Sheets("Data") 

         .Copy Before:=Workbooks(s).Sheets(3)

     end with
End IF
End Sub
```